# Possible to use anonymous type members during declaration?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, anonymous-types

Ok, so I'm trying to turn this:

```
sSelect = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CommitDate, 101) AS XLabel, " +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN NOT CompletionDate IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ClosedEvents, " +
    "COUNT(CommitDate) AS Total, " +
    "COUNT(CommitDate) - SUM(CASE WHEN NOT CompletionDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OpenEvents, " +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN CompletionDate IS NULL AND commitdate < Convert(varchar(12),getdate(),101) THEN 1    ELSE 0 END) AS BehindSchedule";
```

into a Linq query. So far I've got:

```
var vEventsEntriesEnum = dtEventsEntries.AsEnumerable();

var vOpenEntriesData = from r in vEventsEntriesEnum
select new
{
    XLabel = r["CommitDate"],
    ClosedEvents = vEventsEntriesEnum.Sum(closed => (closed["CompletionDate"] != null) ? 1 : 0),
    Total = vEventsEntriesEnum.Count(total => (total["CommitDate"] != null) ? true : false),
    OpenEvents = Total - ClosedEvents,
};
```

which is where I realized I might have a problem. Total and ClosedEvents do not exist in that context.

While I can just go ahead and repeat the queries for ClosedEvents and Total and cast then subtract them or whatever, I was hoping there'd be a better way.

If there are any other ways of doing what I'm doing with the rest of the code, feel free to let me know.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you create an actual class instead of an anonymous type then your property `OpenEvents` can just return `Total - ClosedEvents`

Comment: This might be easier in the long run as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to materialize it somewhere. In query syntax you can use the [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
var vOpenEntriesData = from r in vEventsEntriesEnum
    let ClosedEvents = vEventsEntriesEnum.Sum(closed => (closed["CompletionDate"] != null) ? 1 : 0)
    select new
    {
        XLabel = r["CommitDate"],
        ClosedEvents,
        Total = vEventsEntriesEnum.Count(total => (total["CommitDate"] != null) ? true : false),
        OpenEvents = Total - ClosedEvents,
    };
```

This is similar to a variable in a loop.